# How is this an acceptable question?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3658597). I don't get this one; it is open-ended, asks for general opinions about how to handle GPS in Android systems, and even ends with a section titled "What do i want," which includes this comment:

> I want a solution in javascript or php that can get coordinates from the mobile hardware device, the Native GPS, not the geoLocation, and when the Native GPS is turned off, ask the user to turn on it.

If that's not a request for a tool recommendation or a "please write my code" request, I don't know what is.  Can someone please explain to me what I'm missing that makes this an acceptable post?

Comment: The question is actually a good one: He shows an attempt, understanding of the problem, what's not working, and gives a narrow scope in which the required solution can be created.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Considering the entire question, I don't see it as a "write my code" request. OP posted code and explained what it was doing wrong, and described what result was expected. The last paragraph taken out of context could perhaps be interpreted as you did. However, I think it's grossly unfair to simply ignore the other sections of the post ("My actual method", "My problem", and "Details"). Those contain the core of the question and, in my view, the complete post is completely on-topic for SO.

Comment: I don't really see it that way, even in context. OP didn't ask what was wrong with the posted code; he simply posted his "actual method" and then asked for a solution using either of two languages. Even giving him the benefit of the doubt, it boils down to a request for a tool recommendation.

Comment: @EdCottrell - "I want a solution..." is not at all the same as "show me the code". It's asking if there is another approach (besides the posted code, the deficiencies of which OP clearly explains) that addresses the stated problem. There are a couple of good answers; the one for which OP awarded a bounty doesn't even have any code!

Comment: As I understand it, SO (as opposed to Programmers, Code Review, or other SE sites) focuses on problems with specific code. I don't think the post in question can be read as "I want a solution" for a particular problem with OP's code, so much as "I want a package or drop-in code." Audit questions should be more obvious calls than this, at a minimum.